# Open an index Page from the popup page of a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

i am trying to open an index page from the popup page of a chrome extension. the new opened page should be a normal tab in the browse, i am currently using this line in popup.js but it is not working

```
chrome.tabs.create({ url: chrome.runtime.getURL("index.html") })
```

Comment: The code is correct. Note that the popup is a separate window so it has its own separate devtools: right-click inside the popup and select "inspect" in the menu.